# Is it possible to make an image not visible to a screenshot on a website?

Tags: html, image, drm, netflix

How can I make it not possible to take screenshots of an image (if that's even possible). For example, when going on Netflix, we can see a black screen if starting a screen record.

Can I replicate this with an image on my website? Even if it doesn't fully cover the image from screenshots, just something would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

It is not possible to make an image completely invisible to a screenshot on a website. However, there are ways to prevent users from easily taking screenshots of the image, such as using Javascript to disable the user's ability to take a screenshot.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 44) { // 44 is the key code for the "Print Screen" key
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: I do understand that. When you go to Netflix though, you can not take screenshots without them appearing black. I believe Netflix uses something called "DRM" to do that which is what I am trying to understand better and whether or not it's possible for images.